# Mat-table multiple row within a multiple row

Tags: angular, mat-table

What I want is drawn out in the following image. I use Angular Material (7.x) and use the Mat-Table implementation as described here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

[image]

The above scenario is for the business to show multiple Sales Invoices.

I used Mat Table of Angular already for using multipe rows for one row, and this works. But now I also have to make the first row (Type A) have multiple rows within the multiple row table.

I have some ideas on how to be able to get this working, but I don't want to start and know beforehand if the solution is going to work or not.

I started iterating over the objects in the salesInvoices:

```
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedPurchaseInvoiceColumns"></tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of invoices.salesInvoice">
    <tr mat-row class="table-first-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedSalesInvoiceColumns"></tr>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-row class="table-second-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedPurchaseInvoiceColumns"></tr>
```

This doesn't show anything useful. I think it doesn't even do anything as I only see the purchase Invoices displayed, not the sales invoices.

I was thinking about using a mat-table for the first row? I have no idea how I am able to do so though, I am also not sure if this will work.

I really want to get this working WITH `Mat-Table` but I am afraid I won't be able to get it working with the library of Material and have to make something custom.

Any help is welcome! If I need to provide more information, please tell me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @VarshaBommarabettu See my answer added after your comment below...

Answer (score 3):

### Combine multiTemplateDataRows with when predicate on MatRowDef.

You are looking for `multiTemplateDataRows` in combination with a `when` predicate.

The input `multiTemplateDataRows` is a boolean set on the `MatTable`, see the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable

> Whether to allow multiple rows per data object by evaluating which rows evaluate their 'when' predicate to true. If `multiTemplateDataRows` is `false`, which is the default value, then each data object will render the first row that evaluates its when predicate to true, in the order defined in the table, or otherwise the default row which does not have a when predicate.

The `when` predicate on the `MatRowDef` decides which template should be used for which item. See the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatRowDef

> Function that should return true if this row template should be used for the provided index and row data. If left undefined, this row will be considered the default row template to use when no other when functions return true for the data. For every row, there must be at least one when function that passes or an undefined to default.

**Note:**  *If the `when` predicate on several row definitions returns `true` for the same item, all of those rows will be rendered. If you have multiple row definitions without a `when` predicate, all of those will render.*

---

In other words, you should set the `multiTemplateDataRows` to true, define several row definitions and the `when` predicate of several of those row definitions should return true for the same item (or you don't add a when predicate at all) -> now you rendered multiple rows for your item the "material-table" way...

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
   
  <!-- Your column definitions -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>      

  <!-- Your row definitions -->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; when: yourFirstPredicate"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; when: yourSecondPredicate"></tr>

  <!-- Add as many as you want... -->

</table>
```

Your predicates should something like this:

```
public yourFirstPredicate(index: number, row: any): boolean {
  // some code returning a boolean...
}

public yourSecondPredicate(index: number, row: any): boolean {
  // some code returning a boolean...
}
```

They take the index as a first argument, and the row as a second argument.

---

[Here a working example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-design-rycwm1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: `multiTemplateDataRows` and not multipleTemplateDataRows as you mention (angular 13). Apart from that, this is the solution

Comment: @rmpt I corrected that; was correct in the code example, but I somehow made that mistake in the description in the post...

Comment: @Wilt the number of secondary rows are variable depending on my data object... instead of defining my predicate over and over again (up to some arbitrary limit), is there some dynamic way of doing the `*matRowDef`?

Comment: @ahong Yes, I think something like that should be possible. You might need to break down the structural directive `*matRowDef` to its individual counterparts to do what you want, but I cannot help you without more specifics. Maybe add a new question with an example in a Stackblitz then I can have a look.

Comment: @Wilt I created a question here with a stackblitz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75774550/mat-table-with-row-that-has-varying-of-sub-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can create a two-level nested Mat-table in Angular in which it can expand multiple rows at a time. On each row click from the parent grid it calls an API and loads the data for the inner grid.

Component Code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tableService.getData().subscribe(res => {
      if (res.length == 0) {
        this.panelDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
      } else {
        console.log(res);
        this.panelDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      }
    });
  }

  getDetails(element: any) {
    
    this.tableService.getInnerData(element.Id).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.length == 0) {
        element['innerDatasource'] = new MatTableDataSource();
      } else {
        
        element['innerDatasource'] = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="panelDataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort>
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell (click)="getDetails(element)" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element?.expanded" *ngIf="element?.expanded">
                <div style="width: 100%;">

                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="element.innerDatasource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{innerColumn}}" *ngFor="let innerColumn of innerDisplayedColumns">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{innerColumn}} </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let address"> {{address[innerColumn]}} </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="innerDisplayedColumns"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let address; columns: innerDisplayedColumns;"
                            [class.example-element-row]="address.comments?.length" [class.example-expanded-row]="address?.expanded"
                            (click)="address.expanded = !address?.expanded">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
        [class.example-element-row]="element.addresses?.length" [class.example-expanded-row]="element?.expanded"
        (click)="element.expanded = !element?.expanded">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-bpvhfr?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a model like:

```
export class Model{
parent?: Parent;
children?: Child[];
}
```

Ts:

```
public displayedColumns = ['parents', 'children'];


models: Model[] = [];
//Fill your models from DB and then
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.models);
```

Template:

```
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="parents">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Parent</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <ng-container >
                            {{element.parent.name}}
                            <br />
                        </ng-container>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="children">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Children </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let chl of element.children">
                                {{chl.name}}
                                <br /> 
                        </ng-container>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ytoc4o?file=src/app/app.component.html)