# Mat-table with row that has varying # of sub-rows

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

Trying to use the `mat-table` directives, such as `*matRowDef` and `multiTemplateDataRows` to build a table where each row can have a varying number of sub-rows.

An example interface would look like this:

```js
interface ReportCard {
  student: string;
  reports: Report[];
}

interface Report {
  class: string;
  teacher: string;
  grade: string;
}
```

...where there is no fixed number of reports.

I can easily build a table with `*ngFor`, but I would like to use the built-in Material Table directives.

```js
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>student</th>
      <th colspan="3">
        classes
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>teacher</th>
      <th>grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let reportCard of reportCards">
      <tr
        *ngFor="let report of reportCard.reports; let first = first"
      >
        <td
          *ngIf="first"
          [attr.rowspan]="reportCard.reports.length"
        >
          {{ reportCard.student }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ report.class }}</td>
        <td>{{ report.teacher }}</td>
        <td>{{ report.grade }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think I can also create an arbitrarily high number of templates for data rows using `multiTemplateDataRows` to handle each report (similar to how it is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673290/2088345)), but that does not seem like the best solution. Also I'm not sure I am able to access the correct index for each report while trying to populate the `<td>` cell with the correct data.

[Stackblitz of table I am trying to build](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibcmee?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest transforming your data to a flat array holding both the report-card and its reports before using it as a data-source. In your particular case this will be the easiest and most understandable.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {
  
  private reportCards = REPORT_DATA;
  
  public reportCardColumns: string[] = ['reportCard.student'];
  public reportColumns: string[] = ['report.class', 'report.grade', 'report.teacher'];
  public dataSource: Array<ReportCard|Report>;
  

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const data: Array<ReportCard|Report> = [];
    for (let reportCard of REPORT_DATA) {
      data.push(reportCard, ...reportCard.reports);
    }
    this.dataSource = data; 
  }

  public isReportCard(index: number, data: ReportCard|Report): boolean {
    return Reflect.has(data, 'reports');
  }
  
  public isReport(index: number, data: ReportCard|Report): boolean {
    return !Reflect.has(data, 'reports');
  }
}
```

In your template you can now simply use two when predicates with their own columns and css classes:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="reportColumns" ></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: reportCardColumns; when: isReportCard" class="reportCard"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: reportColumns; when: isReport" class="report"></tr>
```

You can find [a working StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibcmee-u3wxjp?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts).

### Update:

After additional comments [here another Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibcmee-3a2oux?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts) that exactly does what was required in the original question.

Comment: thanks for the answer and stackblitz... if we want the student name to also be a column and instead of multi-colspan row would you suggest the same solution? I'm guess we would have to transform the data differently and might be messier.

Comment: @ahong You could solve that for example by introducing an `empty` column, use it where you don't have data in `reportCardColumns` and `reportColumns` and then define `headerColumns` separately. See example [here in this fork of my previous Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibcmee-isejxv?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)

Comment: I see, I think I know what you mean, but I probably would have to structure the data differently... since I would like to have a table cell that is multi-rowspan instead of multi-colspan, similar to my stackblitz

Comment: OK, now I saw that rowspan in your example. Wasn't clear from the question. [Here another Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibcmee-3a2oux?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html) with how you can easily do that.

Comment: Awesome, yea I guess splicing the data is the best way to do it.